# How to find period of signal, when spectrum is known?

Tags: homework, fourier-series

[image: difficult**Why it can be periodic? **]

Here is signal in frequency domain .Division of frequencies does not give an integer number or real number. May it can be here another method of finding period for ths signal.

Comment: Is your question about one signal, or two signals? I see two different spectrums in the figure.

Comment: Is it a given that the deltas correspond to periodic sinusoids? That is not necessarily the case in general. Also: are you interested in finding _one_ period, or the fundamental period? The latter is much harder to find in general. And finally: see this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/164238/204966

Comment: @MBaz , the one on the right is **almost** equivalent to the spectrum on the left. but $\sqrt{150}$ should be $\sqrt{147}$ and then they would be equivalent.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I agree :)

Answer (score 1):

> Division of frequencies does not give an integer number or real number.

- **real number**: any two real numbers (aside from 0) divided give a real number, so that claim is wrong. Also, doesn't matter.
- **integer**: not a relevant property here.

You should probably look into the definition of *rational* numbers. And hint: Divide your frequency axes by $\sqrt{3}$. That doesn't change the ratio of numbers, but makes things easier to see.

(also, I'm not even saying there *is* a period for both your signals.)

Comment: Division of $\sqrt{3}$ remains the ration of numbers, but how to proof or disproof that this singnals are not periodic?

Comment: That's a new question, but as said, look into the defnition of *rational* numbers. Combine that with the knowledge about the period of the individual components from the spectral plots.

Comment: But what is the knowledge about period of the individual components from the spectral plots?

Comment: lesseee... 5, 7, and 10 are all multiples of **what**?